# formula giving wrong values after copying another sheet

Tags: vba

i have small problem with workbook "data_base" ...after copying the data to another sheet the formula in column "D" should show

like this below

```
"=IF([@[Time Out]]="","",([Time Out]-[Time In])*24)"
```

but its showing as below

```
"=IF(TTM_Form.xlsm!Table2[@[Time Out]]="","",(TTM_Form.xlsm!Table2[Time Out]-TTM_Form.xlsm!Table2[Time In])*24)"
```

and i am not getting the proper results ...can you please let me know how to avoid it.
code line below

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Destination.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Destination.Range("A1").Formula = Origin.Range("F1").Formula
```

Comment: its not working  and Techscript i am not able to understand your code ,how its going to solve the problem
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDestination As Workbook
Dim startDate As Date, Enddate As Date, dtTodayDate As String
Dim Source As Worksheet, Destination As Worksheet ..this is how variables are declared and

Comment: i think this should be under the other answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have table and column names in your formula, naturally you will have the same table and column names after copy/paste.

Suppose that your table layout is as follows:

[image]

**1-** You can either manually amend the formula as `=IF(E2="","",(E2-F2)*24)` and then copy/paste with your code.

**2-** Or you can have the code do it for you:

```
Sub cpy()
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Formula = str(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2"))
End Sub

Function str(rng As Range) As String
Dim brakets As Object, regEx As Object
Dim colname As String, colletter As String
Dim i As Long, colno As Long, rowno As Long
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

str = rng.Formula
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"
    Set brakets = .Execute(str)
    For i = 0 To brakets.count - 1
        colname = Replace(Replace(Replace(brakets(i).submatches(0), "@", ""), "[", ""), "]", "")
        colno = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(colname, Sheets(rng.Parent.Name).Rows(1), 0)
        colletter = Split(Cells(1, colno).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        rowno = rng.Row
        str = Replace(str, brakets(i), colletter & rowno)
    Next i
End With
str = Replace(Replace(Replace(str, "@", ""), "[", ""), "]", "")
End Function
```